# How to update content of an existing jodit editor in a function

Tags: wysiwyg, jodit

i use jodit in my website and wonder, how the content of an existing jodit editor can be updated within a function.

first i do....

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var editor_adressblock = new Jodit('#adressblock', {
    fullsize: false
 });
});
```

and the editor is correctly created.

I have a function, which can be executed by the user and then should load content (via json-request) and then put the content into the existing jodit textarea.
Here is my try (for this example i have simplified the function) :

```
function takeover_adressblock(kunde_id, kunden_adresse_id) {
   // get data by ajax.... not shown in this example
   var data_by_ajax="test";
   editor_adressblock.value=data_by_ajax; // this fails.... 
}
```

Means, i don't know how i can send data to the existing jodit texteditor...

I am a jquery beginner, so please don't be too hard ;-)

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/) you seem to have the right format, so it would help to see the code for the ajax request you're making in case the issue is there.

Otherwise, I would suggest initializing the editor without jQuery in case it's a reference or scoping issue:

```
const editor = Jodit.make('#editor');
editor.value = '<p>start</p>';
```